# Environment variable within variable

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

I have an environment variable called `$TEST` which refers to a directory
in my bash script I have a variable called `$VARTEST` which is  `$TEST/dir/file`

now I want to grep the file specified by `$VARTEST` so I try to do:
`grep somestring $VARTEST` but it doesn't translate `$TEST` into it's directory

I've tried different combinations of `{}`, `""` and `''` but without success

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want

```
eval grep somestring "$VARTEST"
```

or even

```
VARTEST_EVALUATED=$(eval echo $VARTEST)
grep "$SOMESTRING" "$VARTEST_EVALUATED"
```

but remember (as others already said): If possible use

```
VARTEST="$TEST/foo/bar"
```

instead of

```
VARTEST='$TEST/foo/bar'
```

use the second one only if you really need kind of 'lazy evaluation'...

Warning, this could be dangerous if `$VARTEST` contains malicous code.

Comment: that did the trick, however a new problem surfaced, 
somestring in my case is a variable which contains a whitespace $SOMESTRING = "some thing"
now grep searches for some and uses thing as a filename, ie the ""'s are lost

Comment: Ugly, but use eval grep "\"$SOMESTRING\"" "$VARTEST"

Answer (score 1):

Have you put single quotes around something?  Single quotes will prevent the variables from being translated into their corresponding values.  Double quotes will work though.  For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

TEST="/etc"
VARTEST="$TEST/passwd"
grep "$LOGNAME" "$VARTEST"
```